# Chrome extension to delay web page loading

Tags: chrome, productivity

I am looking for a chrome app that can delay web page loading by, say, 15 seconds or so, but only for specific pages. The idea is that this will reduce my incentive to browse productivity-reducing webpages. I know there are apps like StayFocusd, but those don't really lower the incentive as much as just outright block these pages. Does anyone know if such an app exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to suggest few Chrome Extensions after doing a bit of search.Hope my recommendations will fit for what you are looking for!.

- [Delayed Gratification](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delayed-gratification/eacjcpfjdlcdggndfhkmlpnhedggdhke)

> Inspired by XKCD, this extension allows you to add a 30-second delay
>   to the loading of websites you specify. This delayed gratification is
>   a small roadbump that removes the instant reward of going to
>   time-wasting websites, while still allowing you to get to them.

- [Crackbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crackbook/nbgjmohekjolcgemlolblankocjlgalf)

> Crackbook is a Chrome extension for discouraging use of
>   attention-sucking websites such as Facebook or Reddit. The idea behind
>   Crackbook is that delaying access to the website is more effective
>   than straight blocking because you are less likely to just disable the
>   block after a while.The extension will delay every hit to blacklisted site. The delay is just a few seconds initially, but it increases slightly on every hit.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I can't award the bounty for another 22 hours yet, but unless something way better comes along consider it awarded.

Comment: @WouterKuijsters Good to hear! :),but again Its all your choice what we all could do is to recommend ;)

Comment: The link for Delayed Gratification is dead, but there's another extension by that name at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delayed-gratification/ifhndomfnbmggdgodaicfebeggdphlcn

Comment: The link for Crackbook is dead, but there's a more recent fork at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crackbook-revival/fakedinbmdjifniaepnfbplcheaecebc

Answer (score 1):

There is [another chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delayed-gratification/ifhndomfnbmggdgodaicfebeggdphlcn) also named *delayed gratification* that lets your set a time for when the block will be applied again. I found this feature very important.